# $ for jQuery in object literals in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, object-literal

I guess this might be a common question, however I can't find the answer.

I'm working on the structure of my JS for my custom Wordpress theme. I decided to use The Object Literal, because it seems to fit my goals the best and is easy to read.

For my functions that are included into the objects I want to use jQuery selectors with a `$` symbol, but in order to do that I have to redefine `var $ = jQuery;` inside of each function which is an ugly solution. I can't use the global $ symbol because it's not assigned to avoid conflicts with other libraries. I'm not going to use any other libraries that use `$` symbol, but some plugins might, so I would like to keep avoiding potential conflicts.

So my code looks something like this:

```
var myClass = {
    init: function() {
        var $ = jQuery,
            div = $('div');
        div.click(this.addMyClass);
        // And so on...
    },
    addMyClass: function() {
        var $ = jQuery;
        $('body').addClass('newClass');
        // And so on...
    }
}
jQuery(function($) {
    myClass.init();
});
```

Is there a way to avoid re-declaring `$` for every function? Can I pass `$` via init function? Like so:

```
var myClass = {
    init: function($) {
        var div = $('div');
        div.click(this.addMyClass($));
        // And so on...
    },
    addMyClass: function($) {
        $('body').addClass('newClass');
        // And so on...
    }
}
jQuery(function($) {
    myClass.init($);
});
```

Or is it a bad idea? Or maybe there's a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use an IIFE that passes jQuery in as argument

```
;(function($){
 "use strict"; 
  // anywhere inside "$" is jQuery and is insulated from any other libraries

    var myClass = {

        init: function (){
            var div = $('div');        
            div.click(this.addMyClass);      
        }
    };

    $(function (){
        myClass.init();
    });

})(jQuery);
```

This also removes `myClass` from global namespace

Comment: Thank you for a quick reply! I assume the `;` at the very start is a typo?

Comment: actually it helps prevent minification problems if combining numerous files and the previous file is missing a `;` at the end